# Rmarkdown missing TOC HTML

Tags: r-markdown

I have looked at similar questions and have not been able to fix my current problem. I had a working TOC for my HTML document, which has now gone missing. I'm not sure what happened or if I accidently changed something. Here is my code

```
---
title: "Safari Park Analysis"
author: "Data Science Team"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
  toc: true 
  toc_float: true
  toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ##    and ###)
  number_sections: true  ## if you want number sections at each table   header
  theme: united  # many options for theme, this one is my favorite.
  highlight: tango  # specifies the syntax highlighting style
  fig_caption: true
---
```

Comment: Hi, do you have an html template to build the output from? Or is this the standard html output?

Comment: Did you try using just the `html_document` to see if the ToC is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is the YAML part of Rmarkdown, and is VERY specific for it's syntax. Your issue was not adding another indent after `html_document`

Here is me using your initial code with proper indentation and getting the result I assume you wanted, I see you answered your own question, but it's still not clear if you indented properly or not.

```
---
title: "Safari Park Analysis"
author: "Data Science Team"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true 
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ##    and ###)
    number_sections: true  ## if you want number sections at each table   header
    theme: united  # many options for theme, this one is my favorite.
    highlight: tango  # specifies the syntax highlighting style
    fig_caption: true
---


# Chapter 1 

# Chapter 2
```

[image]

But using your answer code, it still renders the same results, NOT using `bookdown::html_document2:`

```
---
title: "Safari Park Analysis"
author: "Data Science Team"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true 
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ##    and ###)
    number_sections: true  ## if you want number sections at each table   header
    theme: united  # many options for theme, this one is my favorite.
    highlight: tango  # specifies the syntax highlighting style
    fig_caption: true
---


# Chapter 1 

# Chapter 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have been able to fix this using the below

output:
html_document:
toc: true
toc_float: true

However, I still don't know why the previous code had stopped working